# How can deal with lists and ranges embedded in a column?

Tags: sql, denormalized

I have no control over the format of the data I am trying to process. I could, of course, use a scripting language to deal with the following problem outside of the database, but I would like to avoid that because of the amount of data I am dealing with and because I'd like to eliminate the necessity of manual steps.

In short, I have a table of lists. A list might consist of a single 3-digit string, more than one 3-digit strings, a range of 3-digit strings, e.g. `012-018`, or a number of 3-digit strings and ranges of 3-digit strings. For example:

```
drop table list;
drop table lists;

create table lists (id varchar, vals varchar);

insert into lists values('A', '001,003-005');
insert into lists values('B', '008-007');
insert into lists values('C', '010, 011, 012');
insert into lists values('D', '011-013, 016-018, 020');
```

*I know*, ***I know***.

I would like to turn this into the following table:

```
create table list (id varchar, val varchar);
```

```
A   001
A   003
A   004
A   005
B   008
B   007
C   010
C   011
C   012
D   011
D   012
D   013
D   016
D   017
D   018
D   020
```

Is there any way to do this in SQL?

Comment: I am actually doing this in a `PROC SQL` in SAS.

Comment: If your question is, can it be done with pure SQL, I would say no, not realistically. Could a SQL guru turn this into codegolf and write a whizbang, incomprehensible SQL statement to do it... possibly. But I wouldn't want to maintain it. Can it be done on the database side with whatever procedural language your particular variety supports... absolutely.

Comment: @Stephanie: That's my feeling as well, but I do not know enough SQL to know what I don't know ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you haven't tagged your question with a specific RDBMS, I'll have to answer generally.

SQL itself doesn't provide the basic operation that you're looking for, which is basically a string split. This means that you'll have to write your own, or use one of the *many* that have been published online.

You've complicated matters a bit, though, with the ranges that you have in your data. This means that your procedure is going to look something like this:

1. Insert your data into a temp/memory table and iterate over it procedurally (or, alternatively, use a cursor to do the same)
2. For each record in your set, extract the non-normalized string data and split it by `','`.
3. For each element within the split data, you'll have to then split *that* by `'-'` (which, for non-range elements, should return you a single result).
4. If your second split (on `'-'`) yields one result, it's a single record that you can insert into your final destination. If it yields two results, then it's a range and you'll have to iterate from the start to the finish (using elements 1 and 2 of that split) and insert records into your final destination

*Edit after comment*

Unfortunately, I don't have any familiarity with PROC SQL or SAS, so I can't provide a specific solution for that. I can post something below in SQL Server T-SQL, which should hopefully get you started.

```
declare @results table (idx int identity(1, 1), id varchar(5), data varchar(max))
declare @elements table (idx int identity(1, 1), element varchar(25))
declare @range table (idx int identity(1, 1), element varchar(25))

insert into @results (id, data)
select
    your_id,
    your_data

from your_source

declare @i int
declare @cnt int

declare @j int
declare @cnt2 int

declare @element varchar(25)

declare @first int
declare @second int

declare @start int
declare @end int

declare @id varchar(5)
declare @data varchar(max)

select @i = min(idx) - 1, @cnt = max(idx) from @results

while @i < @cnt
begin
    select @i = @i + 1

    select @id = id, @data = data from @results where idx = @i

    delete @elements

    insert into @elements (element) 
    select
        element

    from split(@data, ',')

    select @j = min(idx) - 1, @cnt2 = max(idx) from @elements

    while @j < @cnt2 
    begin
        select @j = @j + 1

        select @element = element from @elements where idx = @j

        delete @range

        insert into @range (element)
        select
            element

        from split(@element, '-')

        select @first = min(idx), @second = max(idx) from @range

        if @first = @second --single element
            insert into final_destination (id, value)
            select
                @id,
                element

            from @range
        else if @second - @first = 1 -- two elements, as desired
        begin
            select @start = convert(int, element) - 1 from @range where idx = @first
            select @end = convert(int, element) from @range where idx = @second

            while @start < @end
            begin
                select @start = @start + 1

                insert into final_destination (id, value)
                values (@id, @start)
            end
        end
        else -- error condition, bad input
    end
end
```

Comment: This is better than anything I could come up with myself. I am going to see if I can implement something following this logic before I give up. ;-)